# How to remove published package from the qooxdoo repository?

Tags: package, repository, qooxdoo

I've published a package to *qooxdoo*, but found that I want remove this.

What is the command to remove a package from the *qooxdoo* repository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution atm is to remove package from GitHub profile.

Answer (score 1):

I was advised by the core team to add "(deprecated)" to the About section of the Github project that i wanted removed from the package system. See here for an example: https://github.com/sqville/sqv-qxthemes

Adding this successfully removed this project from qooxdoo.org's package browser site

Comment: but sqv-qxthemes still in package browser...